# Pass HTML input to python script

Tags: python, html

I have a Python script and I want to create a very simple HTML form with 3 fields (username, password and an ID) and a submit button.

When I click Submit I just want to pass these three parameters into my Python script and run the script.

I tried to do it using CGI. I created a `cgi-bin` folder and added my `test.py` file in there. The Python code is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Import modules for CGI handling 
import cgi, cgitb 

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

# Get data from fields
username = form.getvalue('username')
password  = form.getvalue('password')
room_id = form.getvalue('room_id')

#More code here...
```

Then I created an `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form name="search" action="/[path to file]/test.py" method="get">
Username: <input type="text" name="username"> <br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"> <br>
Room ID: <input type="text" name="room_id"> <br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Finally, I added a `server.py` file:

```
import CGIHTTPServer
CGIHTTPServer.test()
```

I run the server.py file and go to 0.0.0.0:8000. I gave the input but when I click Submit the python code is printed in the form and it is not executed.

I am looking for the simplest and fastest way to make this HTML form execute the script. It is only for test purposes and I do not want to spend time creating a complex web application.

Is CGI a good idea? If yes, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you considered using a Python Web Framework? Maybe something lightweight like web2py: http://www.web2py.com/. It shouldn't take a lot of time and is suitable for small web applications.